# Pythonのソースファイルがコマンドプロンプトで読み込めない

Tags: python, windows

Pythonを導入し、以下のリンク先のサイトに沿ってテスト用のソースファイルを作りました。

https://www.python-izm.com/introduction/execution/

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

その後コマンドプロンプトを立ち上げ

```
cd c:¥python
```

と入力して実行するまではよかったのですが`python test01.py`
と入力し実行すると以下の画像のようなエラーが表示され、リンク先のサイトのようにいきません[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ちなみにpathが通ってないのかもと思いウェブサイトを参考にしながら以下の画像のようにpathを設定しました
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
ここまでになにか間違いがあったのでしょうか？
教えてくださると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"指定したファイルが見つからない" というエラーで、作成したファイルと実行時に指定したファイル名とが一致していないのが原因です。

"test01.py" というファイルを作成したようですが、エクスプローラの画面を見ると「テキスト ドキュメント」となっているので、実際に作成されたのは "test01.py.txt" というファイルになってしまっています。

コマンドプロンプトの画面で `C:\python` フォルダにいる状態から `dir` コマンドでファイルの一覧を表示してみてください。

```
C:\python> dir
```

実際のファイル名を確認したら、`ren` コマンドでファイル名を変更してください。

```
C:\python> ren test01.py.txt test01.py
```